# NullPointerException when calling method from another class

Tags: java, swing, oop, nullpointerexception, awt

I am having a problem with a text-based game I'm making. I am fairly new to java and drawing GUI's in java, so I suspect my overall structure might be the root of the problem. So bear with me;

My main class, instantiates a new Gamelobby().

```
class untitledRPG {

public static void main(String[] args) { new GameLobby(); }
}
```

The GameLobby instantiates a MainMenu().

```
class GameLobby {

    {
    mainMenu = new MainMenu();
    }
}
```

The MainMenu() looks like this, and instatiates a GameWindow() if the player chooses the 'New Game'-button, as well as an Intro(), which is where the game-text will come from.

```
public class MainMenu {    

    private String newGame;
    private String loadGame;
    private String settings;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("UntitledRPG™ Main Menu");

    public MainMenu() {
        newGame = "New Game";
        loadGame = "Load Game";
        settings = "Settings";
        buildWindow(frame);
    }

    private void buildWindow(JFrame frame)
    {
        // Main build
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 220);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        // Draw layout with grid
        // Look into GridBagLayout if this proves insufficient
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        JPanel field1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel field2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        JPanel field21 = new JPanel();
        JPanel field22 = new JPanel();
        JPanel field23 = new JPanel();
        field2.add(field21);
        field2.add(field22);
        field2.add(field23);
        JPanel field3 = new JPanel();

        // Instantiate objects
        JLabel welcomeTextLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel gameDescLabel = new JLabel();
        JButton newGameBtn = selectGameTypeBtn(newGame);
        JButton loadGameBtn = selectGameTypeBtn(loadGame);
        JButton settingsBtn = selectGameTypeBtn(settings);

        // Set values. Can be integrated to the instantiation 
        String welcomeText = "Welcome to the Untitled RPG!";
        String gameDesc = "<html>Press 'New Game' to start your adventure,<br /> or 'Load Game' to continue an existing one!</html> ";
        settingsBtn.setText("Settings");
        welcomeTextLabel.setText(welcomeText);
        gameDescLabel.setText(gameDesc);

        //Add objects to panels
        field1.add(welcomeTextLabel);
        field21.add(newGameBtn);
        field22.add(loadGameBtn);
        field23.add(settingsBtn);
        field3.add(gameDescLabel);

        // Add panels to grid
        frame.add(field1);
        frame.add(field2);
        frame.add(field3);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton selectGameTypeBtn(String btnName) {
        JButton returned = new JButton(btnName);
        returned.addActionListener(e -> {
            JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
            if (source.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(newGame)) {
                new GameWindow().openGameWindow();
                new Intro();
                frame.dispose();
            }
            if (source.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(loadGame)) {
                popUp popUp = new popUp();
                popUp.popUpWindow("You have no saves to load!", "Error!");

            }
            if (source.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(settings)) {
                popUp popUp = new popUp();
                popUp.popUpWindow("We haven'made any settings yet!", "Error!");
            }
        });
        return returned;
    }
}
```

GameWindow() looks like this:

```
public class GameWindow {

private JTextArea sideBarArea;
private JTextArea gameArea;
private JTextArea inputAreaTextArea;
private JTextField inputAreaTextField;
private GridBagConstraints c;

 public GameWindow() {
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    int hGap = 5;
    int vGap = 5;
    c.insets = new Insets(hGap, vGap, hGap, vGap);
}

public void openGameWindow() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("UntitledRPG™");
    buildGameWindow(frame);
}

private void buildGameWindow(JFrame frame) {

    /* GameWindow build info
    GameWindow consists of:
    - gameArea, a JTextField where the output from the game will be printed.
    - sideBarArea, TODO
    - inputArea, a JPanel where the player enters commands and views them in a log
     */

    // Main build
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(700, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // Set areas
    gameArea = new JTextArea(5, 10);
    sideBarArea = new JTextArea(5, 10);
    JPanel inputArea = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    // GAME AREA
    gameArea.setEditable(false);
    gameArea.setCaretPosition(gameArea.getDocument().getLength());
    JScrollPane gameAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(gameArea);

    //SIDEBAR AREA
    sideBarArea.setEditable(false);

    // INPUT AREA.
    // Set textArea and add it to scrollpane, which is then added to the layout
    inputAreaTextArea = new JTextArea(10,20);
    inputAreaTextArea.setEditable(false);
    inputAreaTextArea.setCaretPosition(inputAreaTextArea.getDocument().getLength());

    // Message in the inputAreaTextArea to user.
    String welcomeMsg= "This is your command log. Your commands will be printed here.";
    printToLog(welcomeMsg);
    JScrollPane textAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(inputAreaTextArea);

    // (addComp) method for placing elements in gridBagLayout.
    addComp(inputArea, textAreaScrollPane, 0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 2, 2);

    // Label with user instruction on using the inputAreaTextField
    JLabel inputAreaLabel = new JLabel("Enter commands below.");
    addComp(inputArea, inputAreaLabel, 0,2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.2,0.2);

    // Set jTextfield and add it to layout
    inputAreaTextField = new JTextField();
    inputAreaTextField.setText("Start your adventure!"); // Placeholder, see method below
    addComp(inputArea, inputAreaTextField, 0, 3, 2, 2, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.2, 0.2);

    // Listener for enter-click
    inputAreaTextField.addActionListener((e -> {
        if(inputAreaTextField.getText().length() > 0) {
            printToLog(inputAreaTextField.getText());
            inputAreaTextField.setText("");
        }
    }));

    // Method for the placeholder text. Show up one time before textField is in focus
    inputAreaTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            JTextField source = (JTextField)e.getComponent();
            source.setText("");
            source.removeFocusListener(this);
        }
    });

    // ASSEMBLY
    // Set vertical splitpane. Second layer
    JSplitPane vertSplitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, gameArea, sideBarArea);
    vertSplitPane.setDividerLocation(500);
    vertSplitPane.setDividerSize(10);
    vertSplitPane.setEnabled(false);

    // Set horizontal split. Top layer
    JSplitPane horiSplitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, vertSplitPane, inputArea);
    vertSplitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(false);
    horiSplitPane.setDividerLocation(400);
    horiSplitPane.setDividerSize(5);
    horiSplitPane.setEnabled(false);

    frame.add(horiSplitPane);
}

// Easier implementation of constraints for gridBagLayout
private void addComp(JPanel panel, JComponent comp
                        , int x, int y, int gWidth
                            , int gHeight, int fill
                                , double weightx, double weighty) {
    c.gridx = x;
    c.gridy = y;
    c.gridwidth = gWidth;
    c.gridheight = gHeight;
    c.fill = fill;
    c.weightx = weightx;
    c.weighty = weighty;

    panel.add(comp, c);
}

// Prints  player command to inputAreaTextField (log)
public void printToLog(String text) {
    inputAreaTextArea.append(">" + text + "\n");
    inputAreaTextArea.setCaretPosition(inputAreaTextArea.getDocument().getLength());
}

public void printToGameArea(String text) {
     gameArea.append(">" + text + "\n");
     gameArea.setCaretPosition(gameArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
}
```

Intro() looks like this:

```
public class Intro {

Print print;
Player player;


public Intro()
{
    player = new Player();
    print = new Print();
    player = charCreation();
}

private Player charCreation() {
    GameWindow gameWindow = new GameWindow();
    gameWindow.printToGameArea("Wake up");
    player.setAge(21);
    player.setName("Kris");
    player.setGender("m");
    return player;
}
}
```

But when I run this, I get this nullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GUI.GameWindow.printToGameArea(GameWindow.java:138)
at Gameplay.Intro.charCreation(Intro.java:21)
at Gameplay.Intro.<init>(Intro.java:16)
at GUI.MainMenu.lambda$selectGameTypeBtn$0(MainMenu.java:78)
```

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around what is causing this, and how I might improve the overall structure.

Thanks in advance for any help, and please let me know if my question does not meet the SO-standards. I am new to this as well.

Comment: My guess is on `gameArea.getDocument()` returning null.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I am able to use the printToLog() method when writing a command in the inputAreaTextField, and printToLog() uses inputAreaTextArea.getDocument(). I am not able to replicate this by calling printToLog() in intro/charCreation(), so there seems to be something wrong with the way the Intro() methods are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call openGameWindow that eventually call buildGameWindow before calling printToGameArea to initialize the component.

```
private Player charCreation() {
    GameWindow gameWindow = new GameWindow();
    gameWindow.openGameWindow();
    gameWindow.printToGameArea("Wake up");
    player.setAge(21);
    player.setName("Kris");
    player.setGender("m");
    return player;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment! 
Thing is, openGameWindow is called before the Intro(), so running the method again in the Intro class creates infinite GameWindows. So it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood you at first. I called Intro() in MainMenu(), and then called openGameWindow in Intro() and it worked! Thank you very much!